# Best way (performance-wise) to pass a comparison operator as an argument in c++

Tags: c++, performance, lambda, comparison

Consider the following function template that takes an `input` vector and a `value` and finds the elements that are greater than that value and returns the index of those elements through `output`:

```
template <typename T>
void findGreater(const vector<T>& input, const T& value, vector<size_t>& output){
  output.resize(input.size());
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator inp = input.begin();
  vector<size_t>::iterator out = output.begin();
  size_t s = 0;
  for (size_t i; i<input.size(); i++, inp++)
    if (*inp > value)  //<------------------------
      *(out++)=i;
  output.resize(std::distance(output.begin(),out));
}
```

Now I find to implement the same function for other operations, namely: findGreaterEqual, findLess, and findLessEqual. I thought of creating a template function very similar to above which takes an extra `compare` argument as below and implements line shown with //<------------------------, as `if (compare(inp,value))`.

```
template <typename T, typename COMP>
void findGreater(const vector<T>& input, const T& value, vector<size_t>& output, const COMP& compare)
```

Now I can pass different things as `compare`, eg from STL (std::greater, ect), a lambda, a function, a class object that implements operator().

The question is which is a better choice, performance-wise? And is there any other better way to do so?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something for which "better choice, performance-wise" is the same exact answer on every CPU, every C++ compiler, and on every computer in the world. If you need to know which approach gives better performance, the only way you will find out the answer is by trying both and running benchmarks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The code is supposed to run on various platforms (Windows, mac, linux). As far as one method is not quite faster/slower than others on any platform, I am happy and would go with sending "std::less<T>()", etc as arguments.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I disagree. Between lambdas/functors, function pointers and type-erased callables (e.g. `std::function`) we know the relative typical performance characteristics under most conditions, in particular ease of inlining.

Comment: BTW, there is already [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (Since C++11)

Comment: @Jarod42, I am extracting the position of the elements, not the elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers would generate exactly the same thing.

If you had a template function that took a functor, a new function would have to be instantiated for each type. If the type was `std::less`, `std::greater` or some non-capturing lambda type, it is a very easy optimisation to inline the call to `operator()`. Even with a more complicated functor, like a capturing lambda type or a struct with data members, the inlining would probably still be done.

What you do by creating the multiple `findGreater` and `findLess` functions is essentially "manually instantiate" a template.

[An example of the inlining](https://godbolt.org/z/A4nT4E)

Comment: “or some non-capturing lambda type” — whether the lambda captures is completely irrelevant for this: only the size of the `operator ()` matters, not the size of the structure.